# how to calculate number of processors in a pyramid network as 4/3k^2-1/3

Tags: parallel-processing, pyramid-analytics

how to find out the number of processors in a pyramid network is (4/3)k^2-1/3,if k^2 is taking as the network size

Answer (score 0):

we know 4^(n-1) number of leaves will be in 4-ary tree.That means , the depth of a nary tree is 4^(n-1). In this case it is equal to network size of k^2.

hence prove:(4/3k^2 1/3)

take summation of 4^i, i ranges from 0 to n-1

->4^0+ 4^1+...........(GP series)

->(4^n-1)/3

->4^n/3-1/3

->4/3(4^(n-1))-1/3

->4/3k^2-1/3